# How to test hypothesis of no group differences with repeated measures and determine the sample size?

Tags: repeated-measures, statistical-power, equivalence

I want to do a power analysis for a equivalence design but with repeated measures. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed? Also, I want some suggestion on testing the difference of the means with that design?